# Pull column values into new column pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Pandas dataframe that looks like the following:

```
c1 c2 c3 c4
p1 q1 r1 20
p2 q2 r2 10
p3 q3 r1 30
```

I would like to pull the unique values of column c3 and make them into new columns, which would finally look like the following -

```
c1 c2 r1 r2
p1 q1 20 0 
p2 q2 0  10
p3 q3 30 0
```

Is there any ways to achieve this? I am trying with Pivot tables, but not able to get the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.where()` to create the columns `r1` and `r2` separately.

```
# data
# =================================
print(df)

   c1  c2  c3  c4
0  p1  q1  r1  20
1  p2  q2  r2  10
2  p3  q3  r1  30

# processing
# ==================================
df['r1'] = df['c4'].where(df.c3 == 'r1', 0)
df['r2'] = df['c4'].where(df.c3 == 'r2', 0)
df.drop(['c3', 'c4'], axis=1)

   c1  c2  r1  r2
0  p1  q1  20   0
1  p2  q2   0  10
2  p3  q3  30   0
```